# How to find the name of the UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a UserControl repeated 2 times in a web page named FirstUserControl and LastUserControl.

When the user is changing the value of Textbox in FirstUserControl, how can we identify that the user is currently working on FirstUserControl. I mean how can I get the name of the UserControl as "FirstUserControl" in change event of the UserControl.

The following code is a sample. Need to identify UserControl.Name in this.

```
protected void txtAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ControlName = UserControl.Name;

    if(ControlName == "FirstUserControl")
        Response.Write ("You are working on FirstUserControl")

    if(ControlName == "LastUserControl")
        Response.Write ("You are working on LastUserControl")
}
```

Comment: please, add code for your change event

Comment: Is `FirstUserControl` and `LastUserControl` id of the controls you have placed on the ASPX page? Also are you trying to do this identification on server side C# code or through java script?

Comment: Added the sample code. It is written in Server side inside UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sender` argument contains reference to an object, representing a `YourUserControl` that fired this event.

So, you should modify your code as follows to get Parent control (or whatever) of control:

```
protected void txtAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control control = (TextBox)sender;
    while (control as YourUserControl == null)
    {
        control = control.Parent;
    }
    
    string ControlName = ((YourUserControl)control).Name;

    if(ControlName == "FirstUserControl")
        Response.Write ("You are working on FirstUserControl")

    if(ControlName == "LastUserControl")
        Response.Write ("You are working on LastUserControl")
}
```

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bwdsh3.aspx#Anchor_1):

> Server-based ASP.NET Web Forms page and control events follow a standard .NET Framework pattern for event-handler methods.
>
> All events pass two arguments: an object representing the object that raised the event, and an event object containing any event-specific information.

Comment: I don't want the control name inside UserControl. I need UserControl name whether it is "FirstUserControl" or "LastUserControl"

Comment: updated answer. As `sender` is an object, that fired the event, so, if your `UserControl` fired this event - you can get it by casting `sender` to `YourUserControl` class.

Comment: @CPK_2011 if you want to get the name of textbox outside of user control, and this textbox fired this change event and it is placed inside of `UserControl` - you should create an event handler for user control, that will fire, than fired change event for each of textboxes. If so, I can modify code for your needs.

Comment: I don't want the control name inside the UserControl i.e., txtAmount. I can get it directly. Here I want the name of the UserControl that is firing this event.

Comment: @CPK_2011 I can not understand your structure. You have multiple UserControls on the page, which have a TextChanged event, binded to single event handler? Or you have multiple UserControls inside the UserControl `txtAmount` which are binded to `TextChanged` event of UserControl `txtAmount`? Or what?

Comment: I have only one UserControl which is repeated twice in a webpage with names, "FirstUserControl" and "LastUserControl" and this UserControl contains only  one textbox called txtAmount. When the user runs the application, at runtime, I need to know which UserControl, the user is working.

Comment: @CPK_2011 updated answer. As I wrote you can get any of object properties you want, and you can do it with `Parent` property. I have added `while` loop - because I do not know, how many controls are in the hierarchy between UserControl and TextBox